# Is using subscripts for millions, billions... valid?

Tags: ortografía, números

When I was a small kid, at some point they taught me to use this format for numbers:

> 1<sub>4</sub>234.567<sub>3</sub>890.123<sub>2</sub>456.789<sub>1</sub>012.345,6789
>
> <sub>That would be *un cuatrillón doscientos treinta y cuatro mil quinientos sesenta y siete trillones ochocientos noventa mil ciento veintitrés billones cuatrocientos cincuenta y seis mil setecientos ochenta y nueve millones doce mil trescientos cuarenta y cinco coma seis siete ocho nueve* (please edit in an amendment if I'm wrong).</sub>

Is that format still taught? Is it still valid / was it at any point?

I think that's rare. Is it obsolete?

Comment: This question is not about the Spanish language as described in [What topics can I ask about here](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: @VladimirNul why? The Spanish ortography by the Royal Spanish Academy deals with the proper way of writing such big numbers. It tells you how and when to separate numbers in groups of three, how to use the decimal point (or comma), and other questions...

Comment: Note to myself: flag [this](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/31891/obsolete-numbering?noredirect=1#comment57008_31891) as conversational-outdated-irrelevant once a grace period of ten business days has passed.

Comment: Gracias, @23419, por otorgarme los puntos de la recompensa

Answer (score 4):

I also learned this way of writing numbers. It is a very good way to group them, so you can read easily:

However, this is a format that we use just on handwritting and on special contexts, such as teaching.

*Diccionario panhispánico de dudas* says about this in the article [*números*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=QHaq7I8KrD6FQAyXTS):

> 2. Ortografía de los números escritos con cifras. Para escribir correctamente los números expresados en cifras, debe tenerse en cuenta lo siguiente:
>
> a) Al escribir números de más de cuatro cifras, se agruparán estas de tres en tres, empezando por la derecha, y separando los grupos por espacios en blanco: 8 327 451 (y no por puntos o comas, como, dependiendo de las zonas, se hacía hasta ahora: ✖ 8.327.451; ✖ 8,327,451). Los números de cuatro cifras se escriben sin espacios de separación: 2458 (no ✖ 2 458). En ningún caso deben repartirse en líneas diferentes las cifras que componen un número: ✖ 8 327 / 451.

And also:

> d) Las cantidades que tienen como base un sustantivo de significación numeral como millón, millardo, billón, trillón y cuatrillón, siempre que, al menos, las tres últimas cifras de su escritura en números sean ceros, podrán abreviarse mezclando el uso de cifras y letras en su escritura: 327 millones, 3,6 billones, 2 cuatrillones. Son sustantivos, entre otras cosas, porque si se expresa el elemento que cuantifican, este debe ir precedido de la preposición de: 327 millones de habitantes, 2 millardos de dólares. Este método abreviado no es válido para las cantidades en miles, ya que mil no es un sustantivo (la forma sustantiva es millar), sino que forma parte de adjetivos numerales compuestos de dos palabras, en cuya escritura no deben mezclarse cifras y letras; así, no debe escribirse ✖ 154 mil personas o ✖ 12 mil millones, por la misma razón que no escribimos ✖ 30 y siete ni ✖ cincuenta y 4. Debe escribirse 154 000 personas, 12 000 millones (o doce mil millones; → 1.1b).

So *1<sub>4</sub>234.567<sub>3</sub>890.123<sub>2</sub>456.789<sub>1</sub>012.345,6789* would be fine, but if you would write it outside the school you should write either of these:

- 1 234 567 890 123 456 789 012 345,6789
- 1 cuatrillón 234 567 trillones 890 123 billones 456 789 millones 12 345,6789